# Connecting Android to Mongolab

Tags: android, mongodb, mlab, database, nosql

I have a problem connecting my Android app to Mongolab.

```
        String connectionstring="mongodb://user:pass@ds027739.mongolab.com:27739/brokerdatabase";
        MongoClientURI uri  = new MongoClientURI(connectionstring);
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri);
```

Although I used the real user and pass in "...//user:pass@...", this codes crashes in the third line during making client. Would you please let me know if you know what the problem is or I am on the right track or not. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is not a solution, but I think you should make a REST API instead of connecting it directly from Android client. Connecting directly makes it possible to leak the credential.